# Returning a value from a modal in Angular Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the modal directive from Angular Bootstrap to pop up a dialog, change a value (that was passed in) and then retrieve it.

However, for some reason the value never gets updated in the scope.  And, in fact, if I put in a "ng-change" and stick a breakpoint in it, it seems that there's another level of scope being created for some reason.

I've created a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Vy6gLgOJbWcLsHJtaGpV?p=preview

I'm baffled by this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Javascript passes primitives (such as integer) by value. So when you return an integer from the resolve function, or accept it as a function argument, you're using a copy of the original integer. So then changing it (as you do in the popup) will have no effect on the original.

A solution to this is to use an object, and pass that around. e.g. instead of an integer 'hour', use an object time:

```
$scope.time = {
  hour: 12
};
```

and make sure you use it in the resolve object:

```
resolve : {
  time : function() {
    return $scope.time;
  }
}
```

You can see this at http://plnkr.co/edit/8YQGTn79AO4X7Tb7ann7?p=preview

**Edit** : Extracted from the plnkr

```
    var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ui.bootstrap' ]);

    testApp.controller('UserDataCtrl',function ($scope, $modal) {
        $scope.time = {
          hour: 12
        };
        $scope.showPopup = function() {
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl : 'popup.html',
                controller : PopupCtrl,
                resolve : {
                    time : function() {
                        return $scope.time;
                    }
                }
            }).result.then(function(result) {
                $scope.hour = result;
            });
        };

    });

var PopupCtrl = function($scope, $modalInstance, $http, time) {
    $scope.level="PopupCtrl";

    $scope.possibleTimes= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23];

    $scope.time = time;

    $scope.ok = function() {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.hour);  
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    $scope.changing = function(){
        var x = 5;
    };

};
```

Comment: I tried using this solution but  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684781/4989448) actually worked for me; in case someone else would be in need of an alternative.