# Returning data from angular $uibModal backdrop click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to pass back a value from a uibModal. I can define the return if the user clicks the modal's close button

```
$scope.close = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.editMade);
};
```

But this doesn't work if the user click the backdrop area.

How can I define a return value for that particular event?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you click on the backdrop outside, it does a dismiss internally.

Try using this inside modal:

```
$modalInstance.dismiss($scope.editMade);
```

And use this to handle data:

```
 instance.result.then(function(){
  //Get triggers when modal is closed
 }, function(){
  //gets triggers when modal is dismissed. You can basically handle data here
 });
```

Check this working plunker. It uses the dismiss as I mentioned

http://embed.plnkr.co/YdWmqYPFBNbv4vhQZc4t/

**Passing custom data to your parent controller when modal is dismissed:**

Code in Modal Controller:

```
  $scope.$on("modal.closing",function(){
       $rootScope.$broadcast("modalClosing",$scope.editMade);
  });
```

Then in your parent controller:

```
 $scope.$on("modalClosing",function(event,value){
    console.log(value); //value should be $scope.editMade
  });
```

You can learn more by reading the documentation here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs

Comment: I've added the dismiss to my modal, but I'm still unable to pass that variable back to the parent controller

Comment: To relate what I'm trying to accomplish, the plunker line "$log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());" is where I'm trying to return "selectedItem"

Comment: Yes so that is what you have to do? What is the problem that you are facing now?

Comment: "selectedItem" is not available within the $log function

Comment: It simply doens't work. You have to catch in the ModalController the dismiss event and prevent it, so you can close while passing the things you need. Dismissing only passes the type of dismissing.

Comment: reminder to not forget to inject $rootScope into your controller

Answer (score 1):

In the modal controller, you can do something like this:

```
$scope.$on('modal.closing', function(event, reason, closed) {
                if (reason == "backdrop click" || reason == "escape key press")
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $uibModalInstance.close({"data": somedata});
                }                
            });
```

This way you'll always get the success callback on modalInstance

```
modalInstance.result.then(function(response) {
// here response will be whatever is passed. in this sample {"data": somedata}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Amit, I just wanted to Clear the set value for edit, I did as

 $scope.$on('modal.closing', function (event, reason, closed) {
        $scope.ObjectName = {};
        ModalScope.ObjectName = {};
    })