# AngularJS $scope.variable not changing after modal bootstrap popup closes

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Why is `$scope.Templt_Kind_ID` not changing after the bootstrap popup is closed?
Note: I do not close the popup until I retrieve the dropdown value from the popup.

I call a bootstrap popup with edit controls.
After a user changes a dropdown value, it calls
the `$scope.onSelectChangeTemplate_kind = function ()`
In the function below,

```
var ddlID = $scope.selectedCountry; contains the correct value.
$scope.Templt_Kind_ID = ddlID;  // << $scope.Templt_Kind_ID = 34 as it should be
```

Upon closing the popup, I expected `$scope.Templt_Kind_ID =  34`
but it contains `-1` which is what it was first initialized to.

Why? `$scope.Templt_Kind_ID` should =  **34**

JavaScript

```
app.controller('APIController',  function ($scope, $window, $element, $log, $http, APIService) {
    $scope.Templt_Kind_ID = -1; // << Initial value

// Bootstrap popup. After dropdown in bootstrap is changed, this is called.
// I tried a number of things including $scope.onSelectChangeTemplate_kind = function ($scope) 
$scope.onSelectChangeTemplate_kind = function () {
    var ddlID = $scope.selectedCountry; // << contains correct value
    $scope.Templt_Kind_ID = ddlID;  // << $scope.Templt_Kind_ID = 34 as it should be
}

// Bootstrap popup is closed.
// Why is $scope.Templt_Kind_ID=-1 although it shuold be 34 ?????
// Why is $scope.Templt_Kind_ID=-1 although it shuold be 34 ?????
$scope.hide = function () {
        console.log('model one hidden Templt_Kind_ID=' + 
 $scope.Templt_Kind_ID); // <<<<<<
         // << $scope.Templt_Kind_ID is still -1 although it shuold be 34 
        $scope.showModal1 = false;
}
}) 

<html>
<modal-body>
    <div ng-controller="APIController">
        <select id="ddlSelectedCountry" ng-model="selectedCountry"  ng-change="onSelectChangeTemplate_kind()">
            @*3-SP Insert*@
            <option value="">Select Account</option>
            <option 
                    ng-model="selectedCountry"
                    ng-repeat="item in list_Template_kind" value="{{item.Templt_Kind_ID}}"

                    >
                {{item.Templt_Kind_ID}}-{{item.Templt_Kind_Name}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</modal-body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have `ng-model="selectedCountry"` on the `option`s of the select?

Comment: And what do you see when you add `console.log('model one hidden Templt_Kind_ID=' +  $scope.selectedCountry);` in the `hide()` function?

Comment: >>Why do you have ng-model="selectedCountry" on the options of the select?
I hate to say, but I have been working on this for a day and a half and do not remember why I put it in there. 

>>And what do you see when you add console.log('model one hidden Templt_Kind_ID=' + $scope.selectedCountry);
-1

Comment: Well I don't know how or from where you call the `hide()` function, but there is an implementation of the bootstrap components for angular, you might want to try the native modal - http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal it should probably solve your issue

Comment: I call the hide() function from a button in the modal popup 
    <modal-footer>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="hide()">Save</button>
    </modal-footer>

Comment: >> try the native modal - angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal  
I asked about that awhile ago and was told not to use it because we are already using bootstrap ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I recommended in the comments, you can use the native angular module.

Here you open the modal and select the template, when you click `OK` the modal return the selected template back to the controller:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$uibModal', '$log', function($scope, $uibModal, $log) {
  // function to open the Modal from the view, the function accept "selection" argument that will be sent to the model's controller 
  $scope.openModal = function (selection) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'modal.html',
      resolve: {
          // Pass a pre selection template to the Model's controller (pass null if you don't want to pre select)
          selection: function() { return selection; }
      },
      controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance, selection) {
           // save the preselected template and display it on the model's select box 
           $scope.selectedTemplate = selection;

           // Mock of the actual list of templates
           $scope.list_Template_kind = [
                { Templt_Kind_ID: 1, Templt_Kind_Name: 'Template 1' },
                { Templt_Kind_ID: 2, Templt_Kind_Name: 'Template 2' },
                { Templt_Kind_ID: 3, Templt_Kind_Name: 'Template 3' },
                { Templt_Kind_ID: 4, Templt_Kind_Name: 'Template 4' }
           ];

           // OK button was clicked
           $scope.ok = function () {
               // Send the selected template back to the main controller
               $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selectedTemplate);
           };

           // CANCEL button was clicked
           $scope.cancel = function () {
               $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
           };
       }
    });

    // The "$uibModal.open()" returns a promise that resolves when called "$uibModalInstance.close()" from the model's controller
    // or rejected when you call  "$uibModalInstance.dismiss()".
    // You can pass any value to those promise functions from the Model controller and use it in the resolve/reject callbacks 
    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      // Get the selected template sent back from the modal ($uibModalInstance.close($scope.selectedTemplate);)
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      // The user clicked on the "cancel" button
      $log.info('modal-component dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  }
    
 }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">The modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <select id="selectedTemplate" ng-model="selectedTemplate"  ng-change="onSelectChangeTemplate_kind()">
                 <option value="">Select Account</option>
                 <option ng-repeat="item in list_Template_kind" value="{{item.Templt_Kind_ID}}">
                      {{item.Templt_Kind_ID}}-{{item.Templt_Kind_Name}}
                 </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
    
    <! -- Call "openModal" and pass "null" so no pre selection is displayed in the modal --> 
    <button ng-click="openModal(null)">Open</button>
    <! -- Call "openModal" and pass "2" so "Template 2" will be preselected in the modal -->
    <button ng-click="openModal('2')">Open (Preselect 2)</button>
    <! -- Call "openModal" and pass the {{ selected }} property so the last template selected since you last closed the modal will be shown in the modal -->
    <button ng-click="openModal(selected )">Open (Preselect last selected)</button>

     <! -- Show the last selected template in the view (For debugging purposes) -->
    <span ng-if="selected">{{ 'selected - ' + selected }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I am going to press the issue of angular-ui-bootstrap because it seems there are 2 $scope levels when using native bootstrap.  Hey, after a day and a half, what is another day. <smile>   Thanks Alon.

Comment: What do you mean by _press the issue of angular-ui-bootstrap_? If you can demonstrate the issue of the 2 level scope then I might be able to help, but as you can see from my answer - Using a native solution allows you to implement your requirements easily without having to handle the inner scope level (Well, at least with the details provided in your original question).

Comment: The 2 level scope comes from $scope.Templt_Kind_ID = ddlID not actually = 34 AFTER the modal closes.
    var ddlID = $scope.selectedCountry; // << contains correct value
    $scope.Templt_Kind_ID = ddlID;  // << $scope.Templt_Kind_ID = 34 as it should be
  
  
$scope.Templt_Kind_ID is not giving me an error, it just reverts to its original = -1 .
    
    
So I say "2 level scope" because it reverts to -1 eventhough it is set to = 34 upon close.  scope.Templt_Kind_ID = ddlID seems to be going somewhere else.

Comment: saw ONE post about this.  (I wish I saw it yesturday.)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259127/returning-a-value-from-a-modal-in-angular-bootstrap
    
    
As for "What do you mean by press the issue of angular-ui-bootstrap?": I asked about this awhile ago but I was told to keep using regular bootstrap ui since we were already using it.  I totally disagreed but I am not the boss.
    
    
I am going to create (on my own time) your recommendation on angular-ui-bootstrap .  Maybe if they see your answer in action it will be approved.  Your code is much more elegent.

Comment: I did discover a work-around with 
    app.factory('factEdit', function () {
        return { selectedCountry: '' };
    });
    
    
I think your solution is the correct solution... use the native library and will mark yours as solved.  Tommorow, I will post my work around though in case it will help someone else.  And shalom for you.  Thanks very much.

Comment: I ran into another problem with the AngularJS validation and closing the popup after the SAVE button is clicked.  Finding workarounds for the implementation I was told to work with is just too costly.  Alon was correct.  Using angular-ui-bootstrap instead of Bootstrap UI is the correct way to implement the code.  Thanks Alon.

Comment: YAY! Glad to help @JenniferWalters